# Initialization lock for singleton

Tags: java, concurrency, singleton

I'd like someone to double-check my use of Atomic primitives, because multi-threading is hard.

What I don't want to do is locking the whole get method, or having too many pre-checks per get() call.

```
private final static AtomicReference<T> REFERENCE = new AtomicReference<>();

private final static AtomicBoolean IS_CREATED = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public static MyObject get() {
    if (IS_CREATED.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        REFERENCE.set(new MyObject());
    }
    return REFERENCE.get();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As vnp points out, your code is incorrect because a thread may read `REFERENCE` after `IS_CREATED` is set but before `REFERENCE` is set. Here are a couple alternatives:

- use double-checked locking:

  ```
  private static volatile T reference;
  public static T get() {
      if (reference == null)
          synchronized(ThisClass.class) {
              if (reference == null)
                  reference = new MyObject();
          }
      return reference;
  }
  ```
- use static class initialization:

  ```
  private static class Lazy {
      private static final T reference = new MyObject();
  }
  public static T get() {
      return Lazy.reference;
  }
  ```
- use optimistic creation with CAS (this might create multiple instances but only one instance will be returned):

  ```
  private static final AtomicReference<T> reference = new AtomicReference<>();
  public static T get() {
      if (reference.get() == null)
          reference.compareAndSet(null, new MyObject());
      return reference.get();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Feels like the question belongs to stack overflow.

That said, the method is not correct. Consider the scenario:

```
thread 1 executes compareAndSet; IS_CREATED becomes true
thread1 is suspended
thread 2 executes compareAndSet; IS_CREATED is true!
thread 2 returns REFERENCE.get() on an initialized reference
```